# How to use different(small) image for mobile(small) devices in carousel?

Tags: angular, html, css, typescript, carousel

I am using [ngu-carousel](https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel) for displaying carousel images for my application.

I am using the below html for the carousel images

```
 <ngu-carousel #myCarousel [inputs]="carouselConfig" [dataSource]="carouselItems" (onMove)="onmoveFn($event)">
    <ngu-tile *nguCarouselDef="let item;">
     <div class="tile" [style.background]="'url('+item+')'"></div>
    </ngu-tile>
```

For the simple images loading for different device I used the below code before:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="./assets/images/chittu_1400_797.jpg " media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <img srcset="./assets/images/chittu_700_573.jpg" alt="Coastal view of ocean and mountains">
  </picture>
```

How to use media query in the case of carousel which load images like this `[style.background]="'url('+item+')'"` where carousel items is declared as below

```
carouselItems = [
    'assets/images/nature.jpg',];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use media queries in the inline style.

You need to check the document with via JS and define your object accordingly

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
  carouselItems = [
    'assets/images/nature.jpg',];
} else {
  carouselItems = [
    'assets/images/nature_small.jpg',];
}
```